# Shiny Dashboard Not Refreshing

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

The dashboard below has two tabs. Data is refreshed on changing the parameter. The first tab is refreshing properly with change in parameter. The second tab is not refreshed even though the parameter is used with reactive function. The code is very basic with the minimum functionality for testing and demo

The problem is of interaction hence these components are required. Also if you see..from following perspective. 1) data portion will setup the problem 2) 2 tabs are created to show the issue 3) tabs has minimum data displayed to show the failure of refresh...I can say this as I have removed the portion of code which was not directly linked with the problem.

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

get_data <- function(symbols = c("AAPL", "MSFT", "META", "ORCL",
                                 "TSLA", "GOOG")) {
    syms <- getSymbols(symbols, from = "2020/01/01", 
                       to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    map_dfr(syms, function(sym) {
        raw_data <- get(sym)
        raw_data %>%
            as_tibble() %>% # as_tibble will convert to tibble
            set_names(c("OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "VOLUME", "ADJUSTED")) %>% 
            mutate(SYMBOL = sym,
                   DATE = index(raw_data)) %>% 
            select(SYMBOL, DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, ADJUSTED)
    })}

if (!exists("df_all")) {df_all <- get_data()}

df_rep_data <- tribble(~ RunDate, ~ ListStocks,
                       "2020-01-06", "AAPL, GOOG, TSLA",
                       "2021-01-04", "ORCL",
                       "2022-01-04", "META, MSFT") %>% 
    mutate(RunDate = as.Date(RunDate))

make_table <- function(symbol, dat = df_all) {
    dat %>% 
        filter(SYMBOL == symbol) %>% 
        select(DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME) %>% 
        slice(1:5)}
symb_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        tags$h4(textOutput(ns("symbol"))), 
        tableOutput(ns("table"))
)}
symb_server <- function(id, get_symbol_name) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns
        output$symbol <- renderText(get_symbol_name())
        output$table <- renderTable(make_table(get_symbol_name()))
        })}


OneStock_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        tags$h4(textOutput(ns("OneStocksymbol"))), 
        tableOutput(ns("OneStocktable"))
)}


OneStock_server <- function(id, get_symbol_date) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns
        output$OneStocksymbol <- renderText(get_symbol_date())
        output$OneStocktable <- renderTable(make_table(get_symbol_date()))
    })}


ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
            selectInput("run_date", "Run Date", df_rep_data %>% pull(RunDate)),
            tags$h2(textOutput("date_output")), 
            tags$h3(textOutput("lst_symb_output")),
            uiOutput("symbols_output")),
        tabPanel(
            textInput("OneStockChart_input",'OneStockAnalysis', value = 'MSFT'),
            uiOutput("OneStockAnalysis_output"))
    ))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    handler <- list()
    get_syms <- list()
    get_syms_onestock <- list() 
    handler_onestock <- list()
    
    output$date_output <- renderText(req(input$run_date))
    output$lst_symb_output <- renderText({
        df_rep_data %>% 
            filter(RunDate == req(input$run_date)) %>% 
            pull(ListStocks)
    })
    
    output$symbols_output <- renderUI({
        symbols <- df_rep_data %>%
            filter(RunDate == req(input$run_date)) %>%
            pull(ListStocks) %>%
            str_split(fixed(", ")) %>%
            unlist()
        syms <- vector("list", length(symbols)) %>%
            set_names(symbols)
        for (sym in symbols) {
            local({ 
                my_sym <- sym
                syms[[my_sym]] <<- symb_ui(my_sym)
                get_syms[[my_sym]] <<- reactive(my_sym)
                handler[[my_sym]] <<- symb_server(my_sym, get_syms[[my_sym]])
            })
        }
        tagList(syms)
    })
    
    output$OneStockAnalysis_output <- renderUI({
        symbols_onestock <- list(req(input$OneStockChart_input)) %>%
            unlist()
        syms_onestock <- vector("list", length(symbols_onestock)) %>%
            set_names(symbols_onestock)
        for (sym_onestock in symbols_onestock) {
            local({ 
                my_sym_onestock <- sym_onestock
                syms_onestock[[my_sym_onestock]] <<- symb_ui(my_sym_onestock)
                get_syms_onestock[[my_sym_onestock]] <<- reactive(my_sym_onestock)
                handler_onestock[[my_sym_onestock]] <<- symb_server(my_sym_onestock, get_syms_onestock[[my_sym_onestock]])
            })
        }
        tagList(syms_onestock)
    })}

shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```